# Использование в объекте своих же свойств

Tags: javascript, объекты, хеширование

Никак не могу понять в чём ошибка, неужели так делать нельзя...

```js
    let hash = {
        a: 5,
        b: 2,
        all: [this['a'], this['b']],
    };
    console.log(hash.all);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не понятно, где ошибка, надо начать с того места, где не было ошибки и пошагово наращивать код, попробовать поймать место с ошибкой. Например, вывести this для начала:

```js
let hash = {
  a: 5,
  b: 2,
  all: this
};
console.log(hash.all);
```

Здесь это глобальный объект `window` ) Соответственно, у него нет свойств `a` и `b`, оттуда и undefined.

А вот встроенная функция - уже подхватит именно этот объект как this:

```js
let hash = {
  a: 5,
  b: 2,
  all: function(){
    return [this.a, this.b];
  }
};

console.log( hash.all() ); // результат вызова функции
console.log( hash.all ); // сама функция
```

P.s.

```js
let hash = {
  a: 5,
  b: 2,
  c: 1,
};

console.log( Object.keys( hash ) ); // Собирает массив из ключей
console.log( Object.values( hash ) ); // Собирает массив из значений
```